# Increase varnish timeout for a specific path

Tags: varnish

I have a set of scripts on the /admin path that can take a while to execute, and cause Varnish to hit the timeout limit.  Is there a way to increase the timeouts for a particular path rather than for an entire backend?

Answer (score 10):

You may try to add one more backend with same host, but different timeouts

And use it for your urls with req.backend

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "81";
}

backend admin {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "81";
.connect_timeout = 600s;
.first_byte_timeout = 600s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
}

sub vcl_recv {
...
if (req.url ~ "^/admin")
{
set req.backend = admin;
}
..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just recently ran into something like this ..

We added the following in the backends (make sure NOT TO PUT it in the .probe { } sub-declaration [just a small error that caused a hint of confusion for us for a short time ;]):

```
.connect_timeout = 60s;
.first_byte_timeout = 120s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 60s;
```

You can read more about them with 'man vcl'.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use vcl_backend_fetch and set the timeout there:

`sub vcl_backend_fetch {
  if (bereq.method == "POST" && bereq.url == "/slow") {
    set bereq.first_byte_timeout = 300s;
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipe for long requests

```
if (req.url ~ "^/admin/long_request" || req.url ~ "^/upload")
{
    return (pipe);
}

# just add the  Connection: close header
sub vcl_pipe {
    set bereq.http.connection = "close";
}
```